# Upload a file with ServiceStack ss-utils.js

Tags: servicestack

I have a job application form as part of a site built on `ServiceStack`.  I am attempting to use the included `ss-utils.js` to leverage built-in Fluent Validation, but my form doesn't post the user's file upload.  Here's the relevant snippet of the form:

```
<form id="form-careerapplication" action="@(new CreateCareerApplication().ToPostUrl())" method="post">
<div class="error-summary"></div>

<div class="form-group">
    <label>
        Upload Resume
    </label>
    <input type="file" id="Resume" name="Resume" />
    <span class="help-block"></span>
</div>

<input type="hidden" name="Id" value="@Model.Id" />
<input type="submit" value="Submit Application" />
</form>

<div id="success" class="hidden">
Thank you for your application.
</div>

$("#form-careerapplication").bindForm({
    success: function (careerApplicationResponse) {
        $("#form-careerapplication").addClass("hidden");
        $("#success").removeClass("hidden");
    },
    ...
```

Is there something I'm missing in `ss-utils.js`?  Or is there a way of overriding / supplementing the `submit` behavior to use [FormData](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FormData)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turned out I can use the `beforeSend` option as part of the configuration passed into `bindForm` to override the data being sent.  Its a bit of a hack, but it worked and I keep the original `ss-utils.js` fluent validation!

```
$("#form-careerapplication").bindForm({
    success: function (careerApplicationResponse) {
        ....
    },
    error: function (error) {
        ....
    },
    contentType: false,
    processData: false,
    beforeSend: function (x, settings) {
        var fd = new FormData();
        // Tweaked library from https://github.com/kflorence/jquery-deserialize/blob/master/src/jquery.deserialize.js
        // Used to translate the serialized form data back into 
        // key-value pairs acceptable by `FormData`
        var data = $.fn.deserialize(settings.data);
        $.each(data, function (i, item) {
            fd.append(item.name, item.value);
        });

        var files = $('#form-careerapplication').find("input:file");
        $.each(files, function (i, file) {
            fd.append('file', file.files[0], file.files[0].name);
        });
        settings.data = fd;
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Uploading files via a HTML FORM requires a `enctype="multipart/form-data"`, e.g:

```
<form id="form-careerapplication" action="@(new CreateCareerApplication().ToPostUrl())" 
     method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
...
</form>
```

If you want to change support multiple file uploads or change the appearance of the UI Form I recommend the [Fine Uploader](http://fineuploader.com/), there's an example showing how to [use Fine Uploader on the HTTP Benchmarks Example](https://github.com/ServiceStackApps/HttpBenchmarks#fine-uploader).

Whilst Imgur has a simple [client HTML](https://github.com/ServiceStackApps/Imgur/blob/master/src/Imgur/default.html#L74) and [Server example](https://github.com/ServiceStackApps/Imgur/blob/master/src/Imgur/Global.asax.cs#L57).

Comment: Didn't actually work using ss-utils.js `bindForm`.  The problem is the file input wasn't serialized into the data parameter in the $.ajax call.  See my answer below.